# ProgressBar - Not Updating in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hi just had a quick question about why my progressbar isn't updating. I will add comments in the below to demonstrate what is working and what isn't.

To my knowledge it should be working since it updates in an asynctask.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (!(data.get(position) instanceof TemporarySongInfomation)) {
        SongViewHolder holder;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_format, null);
        holder = new SongViewHolder();
        holder.timesplayed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        holder.imagebutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tempValue = (SongInfomation) data.get(position);
        String songName = tempValue.getName();
        holder.imagebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton1);
        holder.source.setText(tempValue.getVideoid());
        holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
        holder.timesplayed.setText("" + tempValue.getTimesplayed());
        holder.artist.setText(tempValue.getArtist());
        swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
        view.setOnClickListener(new SongListOnItemClickListener(position));
        view.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
        holder.imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnPlayButtonClickListener(position));
    } else {
        TemporarySongViewHolder holder;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_process_format, null);
        holder = new TemporarySongViewHolder();
        holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artisttemp);
        holder.bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ppbar);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titletemp);
        holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sourcetemp);
        tempValue1 = (TemporarySongInfomation) data.get(position);
        String songName = tempValue1.getName();
        holder.source.setText(tempValue1.getVideoid());
        holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
        holder.artist.setText(tempValue1.getArtist());
        holder.bar.setMax(100);
// the below line starts the task!
        new UpdateProgressBar(holder.bar, tempValue1).execute();

    }

    return view;
}

private class UpdateProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private TemporarySongInfomation songinfo;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    UpdateProgressBar(ProgressBar bar, TemporarySongInfomation tp) {
        progress = bar;
        songinfo = tp;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!songinfo.isCompleted()) {
            System.out.println("going " + (int) songinfo.getProgress());
// the above line prints different values for songinfo.getProgress()
            progress.setProgress((int) songinfo.getProgress());
            publishProgress();
            System.out.println("Progress "+progress.getProgress());
// the above line only prints "Progress 0"
// and obviously the ui doesnt update.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still having problem will repost i guess

Comment: Please don't change your post that much. It makes existing answers irrelevant and the whole post will be unhelpful for futures users with the same problem. If you are still having trouble after attempting to solve the problem and with thorough research, then feel free to post a new question

Comment: Well actually I implemented their changes. I only posted because I did research and failed to implement it properly. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I understand that you implemented their changes but that shouldn't be done in your post. Accepting the answer, as you have, lets others know that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

publishProgress(Progress...) calls onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) invoked on the UI thread after a call to
>   publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.

so basically you need to update the UI thread from onProgressUpdate method.

Here an example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong

```
progress.setProgress((int) songinfo.getProgress());
publishProgress();
```

You need to update the progress bar from the UI thread.  So to update progress, you must override `onProgressUpdate`, which is run on the UI thread, and update your progress bar from there.

in `doInBackground`, do this

```
publishProgress((int) songinfo.getProgress()); // this calls onProgressUpdate on the UI thread
```

then, in `onProgressUpdate`, do this

```
progress.setProgress(values[0]);  // called on UI thread
```

You will also need to change your `AsyncTask` class definition

```
private class UpdateProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> { // Integer progress type
```